# Invitations between the two models Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, invitation

I have two models. Weddings and guests.

```
class Wedding
  has_many guests
end

class Guest
  has_many weddings
end
```

How do I make what guests can accept or decline the invitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a many to many relation with an intermediate model. See [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many). See **2.4 The has_many :through Association** topic [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

On that new model/table you can add an attribute (a boolean "decline" attribute maybe) to control guests assistance...